# Finding connection between two tables and copying one tables data to another table with different column name and same data

Tags: sql, oracle, file-copying

I have two tables I want check the connection path(DB link ) between two tables and copy one tables data to another table with different column name and same data

Comment: Could you please tell us what you've done so far, what exactly is your question and where we can replicate this?

Comment: I have TABLE_A and TABLE_B (diff connections)  the data is same in the two tables but column are different for example NAME AGE DOB(table A) and USERNAME AGE DOB (table B) want copy table a data to table B.  and how to find the link between 2 tables.  want a query to do this operation

Comment: If the data is the same in both the tables, why do you want to copy it?

Comment: I have dB link and username and password for that how to connect to another db with this link

Comment: Same data in the sense similar data @ karthik_ghorpade

Comment: CAN anyone has a proper resolution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a database link; it is used when schemas reside in different databases. Therefore, you'll first have to create a database link (if it doesn't exist yet) and then

```
insert into table_b@db_link (username, age, dob)
  select name, age, dob
  from table_a;
```

---

Otherwise, if schemas reside in the same database, you'll just have to **grant** certain privileges from user (that owns table B) to user (who owns table A):

```
connect user_b
grant insert on table_b to user_a

connect user_a
insert into user_b.table_b (username, age, dob)
  select name, age, dob
  from table_a;
```